# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when deploying Spring Boot Application on JBoss EAP 7.4.0

Tags: spring-boot, jboss, jakarta-migration

I'm trying to deploy my Spring Boot application on JBoss EAP 7.4.0, and I'm encountering the following error:

I suspect there might be a conflict or missing library related to the transition from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*`, but I'm not sure how to address it. 1. I'm using Spring Boot version [Your Version Here]. 2. The application is packaged as a `.war` file for deployment. 3. I've made sure the necessary JSP and JSTL dependencies are included in the `pom.xml`. Has anyone faced a similar issue or can provide guidance on how to resolve it? Thank you.

```
2023-10-06 09:01:39,931 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYEE0007: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.PasswordInputTag due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
2023-10-06 09:01:39,931 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-7) Failed to define class org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.AbstractHtmlElementTag in Module "deployment.ivr-adapter-0.0.1.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/AbstractHtmlElementTag (Module "deployment.ivr-adapter-0.0.1.war" from Service Module Loader): jakarta/servlet/jsp/tagext/DynamicAttributes
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1090)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:753)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1090)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:753)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:21)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:80)
        at org.jboss.as.server@15.0.2.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

2023-10-06 09:01:39,931 WARN  [org.jboss.modules.define] (MSC service thread 1-7) Failed to define class org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.HiddenInputTag in Module "deployment.ivr-adapter-0.0.1.war" from Service Module Loader: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/HiddenInputTag (Module "deployment.ivr-adapter-0.0.1.war" from Service Module Loader): Failed to link org/springframework/web/servlet/tags/form/AbstractHtmlElementTag (Module "deployment.ivr-adapter-0.0.1.war" from Service Module Loader): jakarta/servlet/jsp/tagext/DynamicAttributes
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1090)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:753)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1090)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.doDefineOrLoadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:424)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:555)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:339)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader$1.loadClassLocal(ModuleClassLoader.java:126)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.loadModuleClass(Module.java:753)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:247)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:410)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
        at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.ee.utils.ClassLoadingUtils.loadClass(ClassLoadingUtils.java:21)
        at org.jboss.as.ee@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:80)
        at org.jboss.as.server@15.0.2.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:182)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
        at org.jboss.msc@1.4.12.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Here is my pom.xml file

I suspect there might be a conflict or missing library related to the transition from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*`, but I'm not sure how to address it.

1. I'm using Spring Boot version 3.1.2. 2.

The application is packaged as a `.war` file for deployment.

3. I've made sure the necessary JSP and JSTL dependencies are included in the `pom.xml`. Has anyone faced a similar issue or can provide guidance on how to resolve it? Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.assistt</groupId>
    <artifactId>ivr-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <name>ivr-adapter</name>
    <description>IVR Adapter </description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvoicexml</groupId>
            <artifactId>main</artifactId>
            <version>0.7.9</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/libs/org.jvoicexml.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
          <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
          <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.8</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>start</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>stop</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
                <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JBoss EAP 7.4.0 is Java/Jakarta EE 8. You are using JakartaEE 9/10 applicaiton it won't work: **jakarta/servlet/jsp/tagext/DynamicAttributes**